# Touch ID doesn't work on MacBook Pro 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I have troubles with Touch ID on my MacBook Pro 2019 all the time, it just don't recognize my fingers. If I try to add a new fingerprint the red lines animation doesn't show up like nothing is touching the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to take my laptop to repairs but accidentally discovered the offender is my **LED desktop lamp**. My laptop usually sits on a stand and there is a desktop lamp shining right on the keyboard from about ~50cm. If I turn the lamp on - Touch ID stops working, if I turn the lamp off - it does work flawlessly. It seems like bright LED light shining on my finger somehow interferes with Touch ID sensor. Go figure!